# How to get value of the last changed option on a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Pure jQuery version:

```
$('select#register-type').live('change', function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Backbone view delegate event version:

```
App.Views.register = new (Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  id: 'content',

  template: _.template($('script.register').html()),

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    'change select#register-type': 'type'
  },

  type: function (event) {
    // i want to console.log the current option selected... 
  }
}));
```

How can I achieve that? It seems i cant use $(this) like the jquery version, and this is referred to the register view object...

Comment: 'select#register-type' <-- FYI select is useless here. if you're looking up an element by ID, the ID itself will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`event.target`**

```
 type: function (event) {
    $(event.target).find('option:selected').val();

      **OR**

     $(event.target).val();
 }
```